# Why is Qunit not catching my 2+ tests being run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jquery-mobile, qunit

I'm trying to get a sequence of tests to work in Qunit. I'm working with JQM and am using their testsuite, which includes a `$.mobile.testHelper` object, which I'm adding methods to.

Here is my code (with comments and logs):

```
// my test page is loaded inside an iframe
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
var d = frame.contentDocument;
var w = frame.contentWindow;
var $i = w.$(d);
var $body = w.$("body");

// forcing $(body) as event target
$.testHelper.eventTarget = $body;

// sets "one" listener on "step" event and jumps to next method when triggered
$.testHelper.stepSequence = function (fns) {
    $.testHelper.eventSequence("step", fns);
};

// run a test
$.testHelper.runTest = function (command, condition) {
    console.log("RUNNING TEST...");
    ok(condition, command);
};

// try 10x if a condition is met, wait 1000ms in between
$.testHelper.countDown = function (arr, command) {
    var condition, is_done;
    var ticker = 0;
    var i = w.setInterval(function () {

    switch (command) {
        case "verifyAttribute":
            condition = $i.find(arr[0]).eq(0).attr(arr[1]).indexOf(arr[2]) > -1;
            break;
        case "waitForElementPresent":
            condition = $i.find(arr[0]).length > 0;
            break;
        }
        if (condition) {
            console.log("CONDITION PASSED, RUN TEST");
            $.testHelper.runTest(command, condition);
            w.clearInterval(i);
        }
        ticker += 1;
        console.log(ticker);
        if (ticker === 10) {
            console.log("FAILED, RUN WITH undefined to fail test");
            $.testHelper.runTest(command, condition);
            w.clearInterval(i);
        }
    }, 1000);
};

// my test module
module("UI Basic Interaction");
asyncTest("${base_url}", function () {
    expect(2);

    // here is my sequence of methods
    $.testHelper.stepSequence([
        function () {
            w.setTimeout(function () {
                $body.trigger("step");
            }, 800);
            $.testHelper.countDown(["div#global-panel", undefined, undefined],         "waitForElementPresent");
        },
        function () {
            w.setTimeout(function () {
                $body.trigger("step");
            }, 800);
            $("a:contains('Menu')").trigger("click");
        },
        function () {
            w.setTimeout(function () {
                $body.trigger("step");
            }, 800);
            $.testHelper.countDown(["div#global-panel", "class", "ui-panel-open"], "verifyAttribute");
        },
        function () {
            w.setTimeout(function () {
                $body.trigger("step");
            }, 800);
            $("h1:contains('My Account')").trigger("click");
        },
        function () {
            start();
        }
    ])
});
```

I need to trigger "step" AFTER the test conditions runs, but can't get it to work, so I'm using the no-nice `setTimeout`

My problem is that the first test passes, the 2nd test correctly starts the interval, while the UI renders, but when the element is found, QUNIT errors out with `Expected 2 assertions, but 1 were run` pretty much at the same time my console reports the condition to be true.

**Question:**
From the code above, is there an error in my test routine, that does not run `runTest` "fast" enough, because Qunit errors out? Also I would be happy for a nicer way to triggering `"step"`.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with JQM `testhelper`, but it looks like your `countDown` function could wait up to 10s, but `QUnit.start` will run after about 4x800ms.

Comment: True, playing around with the timing now.

Comment: @psquared: helped, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After much meddling:

What was wrong:

- My click selector was `$(element:contains(...)` which searched the document vs the iframe `$i.find("eleme...` fixed this.
- I added a 2nd listener for **test_runner**, which triggers once a test runs. Only after all tests are run, I trigger `start()`. This way Qunit has to wait :-)

and the working code (see comments (1), (2), (3) for changes):

```
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
var d = frame.contentDocument;
var w = frame.contentWindow;
var $i = w.$(d);

// (1) set counter for tests ran 
// This allows to trigger start() after all tests are done
var test_log = 0;
var $body = w.$("body");

$.testHelper.eventTarget = $body;
$.testHelper.stepSequence = function (fns) {
    $.testHelper.eventSequence("step", fns);
};
$.testHelper.runTest = function (command, condition) {
    ok(condition, command);
    $body.trigger("step");
    // (2) When running a test, also trigger a runner on body to log no of tests
    $body.trigger("test_runner");
};
$.testHelper.countDown = function (arr, command) {
    var condition, is_done;
    var ticker = 0;
    var i = w.setInterval(function () {
        switch (command) {
        case "verifyAttribute":
            condition = $i.find(arr[0]).eq(0).attr(arr[1]).indexOf(arr[2]) > -1;
            break;
        case "waitForElementPresent":
            condition = $i.find(arr[0]).length > 0;
            break;
        }
        if (condition) {
            console.log("PASSED TEST");
            $.testHelper.runTest(command, condition);
            w.clearInterval(i);
        }
        ticker += 1;
        if (ticker === 10) {
            console.log("FAILED");
            $.testHelper.runTest(command, condition);
            w.clearInterval(i);
        }
    }, 1000);
};

module("UI Basic Interaction");
asyncTest("${base_url}", function () {
    expect(2);
    $.testHelper.stepSequence([
        function () {
        // (3) set a listener for tests ran
        // once all tests are done, start()
            $body.on("test_runner", function (e) {
                test_log += 1;
                if (test_log === 2) {
                    start();
                }
            });
            $body.trigger("step");
        },
        function () {
            $.testHelper.countDown(
                ["div#global-panel", undefined, undefined], 
                "waitForElementPresent"
            );
        },
        function () {
            $i.find("a:contains('Menu')").trigger("click");
            $.testHelper.countDown(
                ["div#global-panel", "class", "ui-panel-open"], 
                "verifyAttribute"
            );
        },
        function () {
            $i.find("h1:contains('My Account')").trigger("click");
        }
    ])
});
```

Viola. Works nicely.